# Checkbox state not preserved

Tags: flutter, dart, key, state

I've made a custom checkbox widget in dart and used a global key to save the state.

```
class CheckBox extends StatefulWidget {
final String label;
final void Function(dynamic) onChanged;

const CheckBox({required this.label, required this.onChanged, Key? key})
  : super(key: key);

@override
CheckBoxState createState() => CheckBoxState();
}

class CheckBoxState extends State<CheckBox> {
 final key = GlobalKey();
 late bool isChecked;

 @override
 void initState() {
   isChecked=false;
   super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
     child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Text(widget.label, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
      KeyedSubtree(
        key: key,
        child: Checkbox(
          activeColor: LightSeaGreen,
          checkColor: White,
          value: isChecked,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              isChecked = !isChecked;
            });
            widget.onChanged(value);
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

I've populated a list of checkboxes using the above widget as below,
[image]
[image]

when I select the checkboxes in one category (i.e. certificate provider ) and check the checkboxes in the course language category, the selected checkboxes of the certificate provider remains unchecked (**the state is not saved**).What can I do to save the state when I go from from one category to another? Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: When you change category, your 'CheckBox' widget is built and 'initState' is called and reset value to false. So you need to store parent widget with category and value.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Global key to preserve state of all your responces. you should use a class (factory) to save your responces and use a state management library to handle your responces maybe, provider will work well. Or, you can use a local data base like hive to store your responces and you can fetch these responces whenever you want that will be best pratice.
Thank you